# What is the alternative of "primarily....secondarily,.... and thirdly,.... "?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I am writing a scientific manuscript in which I have to describe an experimental protocol. The used sentence should show the priority of picking up biological samples depending on their origins.

The used sentence structure might look like the following:

> ...was primarily selected according to sources from the Mus Musculus
>   species sera, cells or tissues, then secondarily, from Rattus norvegicus
>   species, and thirdly, from human sera.

Since this sentence structure was used previously in other manuscripts to describe the same protocol, it was detected as "high plagiarism" by authentic software tools.

My question is how to describe the same priority without using this common structure "primarily....secondarily,.... and thirdly,.... " ?

Comment: Plagiarism has nothing to do with sentence structure on its own. It's either the sentence exactly as written, or the content. If you take the same content but switch the phrases around, it would still be considered plagiarism.

Comment: It's a little difficult to give an equivalent sentence, because the extract you provide does not describe sufficiently what meaning you are trying to convey. I gather you have taken samples from mouse, rat or human, but don't know the criteria for selection of one or another. Can you give a little more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

If (for some reason) you do not wish to use *primarily, secondarily, etc.*, you can substitute other descriptions - and they do not need to increment. Example:

> *...was first selected according to ... tissues, then from ... species, then from ....*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simply saying what you stated that you mean:

> "...was selected from (in order of priority): the Mus Musculus species sera (cells or tissues), Rattus norvegicus species, and human sera.